# codeigniter 2.x.x validation error highlighting

Tags: php, codeigniter

where/what file to tweak in order to alter the background color of the form_validation error ? , like e.g I want to change the color to red, so that it stands out on my registration form, when it detects an error when user enters inappropriate data

Comment: Learn to use the CSS tools in your browser and inspect the element to see what styles apply to it, or just read through each CSS file on the page to see which has the styles matching the class/id of the error.

Answer (score 2):

First you should mark the errors, changing the error default delimiters:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

and then style the error class in your css, like

```
.error {
    background:#FBE6F2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:1px solid #D893A1;
    color:#333333;
    margin:10px 0 5px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

check into the documentation [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)